# imagecreatefromstring() doesn't output image

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP OOP, and I'm doing a tutorial that I found online.  I've found that this code from the tut might be creating a variable with image contents, but I'm not sure how to verify this.  These methods are new to me.

```
        // read the image file to a binary buffer
        $fp = fopen($filename, 'rb') 
            or die("Image '$filename' not found!");
        $buf = '';
        while(!feof($fp))
            $buf .= fgets($fp, 4096);

        // create image
        imagecreatefromstring($buf);
    }
}
$image = new Image("image.gif"); 
?>
```

What would be the best way to call the $image variable to display the image in the browser?  At first I thought that was what this code should do.  I'm not getting an error that the image is not found, so at least I can rule that out.  The image I'm using is 71kb.  Thanks!

To add to the comments, I see that there is one answer that addresses this question, but I was happy to find within this thread an answer that directly looks at the code I posted, as opposed to a completely rewritten code.

Comment: "Won't work" isn't really a problem description.

Comment: the code does more or less nothing (but it should work), because `imagecreatefromstring` would return a resource (of the image) but that is never assigned to a variable and used. it usually helps if you say what you actually want to do

Comment: Yes, ok, let me edit this to better describe the issue.

Comment: look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416652/need-help-understanding-this-php-code?rq=1 . that is exactly your code, and it is explained very well in the answer

Comment: @x4rf41 's link is good -- and I amended my answer to supplement that. Good luck learning OOP !

Comment: Yes, I got some knowledge from x4's link, and also from your answer as well.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so when you call `new Image()` - you're calling the `__construct()` function --

You likely know this already.

The `__construct()` function, however, is not outputting anything.

Just for example, if you put `echo` in front of `imagecreatefromstring` - then you can see some output. Otherwise, the function does not output anything, itself.

In the case of this function, however, you have to tell PHP how to output it (`echo` is for strings)

So, when in doubt, [RTM:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($buf);
if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im); 
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```

NOW, since you're learning oop, let me explain a bit more --

The purpose of your `__construct` function should be fairly obvious - but when you're dealing with objects and classes, you'll want to separate different functions --- thus, the code snippet above should go in its own function, so the end result would be something like:

```
<?php

class Image{         

  private $image; //this variable, or 'property'(in OOP Classes) will be shared 


public function __construct($filename){


        $fp = fopen($filename, 'rb') 
            or die("Image '$filename' not found!");
        $buf = '';
        while(!feof($fp))
            $buf .= fgets($fp, 4096);

        // create image
      $this->image =  imagecreatefromstring($buf);
    }

public function renderImage(){
    if ($this->image !== false) {
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        imagepng($im); 
        imagedestroy($im);
        } 
    }

}
$image = new Image("image.gif"); 
$image->renderImage();
```

Comment: `echo` would just return the resource id since `imagecreatefromstring` returns a resource

Comment: Right, right - I edited accordingly. Thank you

Comment: yes, that should work, its still kinda weird to output an image in the constructor of an `Image` class :D. That kinda defeats the purpose of OOP

Comment: OH man, I completely overlooked that.